# How to 'package' advanced actions and set triggers in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have created two actions in code, one simple and one advanced.

```
function userbeep_action_info() {
    return array(
        'userbeep_beep_action' => array(
            'type' => 'system',
            'label' => t('Beep annoyingly'),
            'configurable' => FALSE,
            'triggers' => array('node_view', 'node_insert', 'node_update', 'node_delete')
        ),
        'userbeep_multiple_beep_action' => array(
            'type' => 'system',
            'label' => t('Beep multiple times'),
            'configurable' => TRUE,
            'triggers' => array('node_view', 'node_insert', 'node_update', 'node_delete')
        )
    );
}
```

Now the simple action (i.e. the non-configurable one) will appear in my Triggers menu automatically, but I need to create the advanced one in `admin/config/system/actions` before I can use it.

What I'd like to do is have my module automatically create the advanced action. There are two ways I can see this working:

1) Add something to an .install file to install and uninstall upon loading the module.

2) Package these settings using Features

Ideally, I'd like to do this programmatically using 1), but I'm also keen to learn about Features. I installed the module but saw no obvious way to do this.

Moving forwards, would there also be a way to package / set up the Trigger using these actions so that the user doesn't have to set this up manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can use the Actions API methods - `actions_save` and `actions_delete` for this. (See includes/actions.inc).

**hook_install()**,

```
// Action configuration parameters that you can also set by clicking on the 
// Configure link that shows next to a configurable action in
// admin/config/system/actions
$config['beep_count'] = 10;
$config['beep_file'] = 'sound.mp3';
$aid = 
  actions_save(
    'userbeep_multiple_beep_action', // Name of the action callback method
    'system', // Action group
     $config, // An array of key-value pairs
     t('Beep multiple times'), // Action label helpful in the Trigger UI
     NULL // Create a new action
  );
variable_set('my_module_actions', array($aid));
```

**hook_uninstall()**,

```
$aids = variable_get('my_module_actions', array());
if (!empty($aids)) {
  actions_delete($aids);
}
```

2) Does Features support exporting actions? For packaging non-configurable actions, `hook_action_info()` is good enough, I feel.

3) Again, using code, you can explicitly *assign* actions to triggers by adding entries to the `trigger_assignments` table as shown below:

```
$query = db_insert('trigger_assignments')->fields('hook', 'aid', 'weight');
$hooks = array('node_insert', 'node_update', 'node_view', 'node_delete');
foreach ($hooks as $hook) {
  $query->values(array(
    'hook' => $hook,
    'aid' => 'userbeep_multiple_beep_action',
    'weight' => 0
  ));
}
// Multi-value insert
$query->execute();
```